# context variables in DRF generic view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build some frontend stuff in  DRF - react. someAPI should run a query against db using current logged user id as parameter. After some hours trying here and there, following code works, but Im not sure is the right way to do it as involves using mixins and function overriding.

Question is, How can I achieve same result using generic DRF views?

```
class someAPI(mixins.ListModelMixin,
              generics.GenericAPIView):

serializer_class = someSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    customRole = get_object_or_404(Role, user=request.user)
    self.queryset = ClassDependingOnRole.objects.filter(role=customRole.id)
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs) 

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ListCreateAPIView directly.It is more useful.

```
class SomeApi(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer    

    def get_queryset(self):
        role=get_object_404(Role, user=self.request.user)
        return ClassDependingOnRole.objects.filter(role=role)
```

It generates post and get methods automatically and validates serializer validations.You da find more detail from [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) about ListCreateAPIView.

Comment: Thank you! Already tried using `get_queryset`, but didnt work as dont accept `request ` as parameter by default, that means `request.user` returns `None`. I'm afraid that happens with context variables. Thats why I did override `get(self, request,...)` and not `get_queryset(self)` Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: I did a wrong, it is not request.user it must be self.request.user.I changed it. And I didn't understand context variables, can you tell me?

Comment: Yeah @kamilyrb you right. With your latest edit it works. Looks like I have to look deeper in documentation as generic views have request properties within themselves. TY!